# Apache added a ? in .htaccess 301 Redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, expressionengine

I'm redirecting this URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/expandyourtaste
```

Using this .htaccess file:

```
#Expand your tastes redirects
Redirect 301 /expandyourtaste http://mydomain.com/mobile
Redirect 301 /expandyourtaste/tastyextras http://mydomain.com/mobile/tasty_extras
Redirect 301 /expandyourtaste/coffee http://mydomain.com/mobile/coffe
Redirect 301 /expandyourtaste/400Calorie http://mydomain.com/mobile/400calories
Redirect 301 /expandyourtaste/Kidsstuff http://mydomain.com/mobile/kids_stuff
Redirect 301 /pickyourpasta http://mydomain.com/mobile/pickyourpasta
Redirect 301 /newpastaentrees http://mydomain.com/mobile/newpasta

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Expression Engine
# I BELIEVE THE ISSUE LIES HERE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
AcceptPathInfo On

</IfModule>

# enable gzip compression
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>

# force download pdfs
AddType application/force-download .pdf

#Increase File Upload Size
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

The issue is that when the URL is redirected, is ends up like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/mobile?/expandyourtaste
```

I think I have narrowed down the issue to the marked section in the code. Do you see the issue?

Comment: I thought so. Can you offer a fix?

Comment: re my first comment, that one was incorrect, sorry. Is the additional `s` in `expandyourtastes` intentional or a typo?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what happens here, but this line must be the final culprit *somehow:* `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` Do you need that `?` in the first place? (edit: @MPD gives a good possible explanation)

Comment: To find out if it was caused by the rewriterules, try to enable the [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you convert your `Redirect` statements to `RewriteRule`?  `mod_rewrite` executes before `mod_alias`, regardless of the order in your `.htaccess`.  Mixing the two can cause weirdness.

Edit:

Take a look at http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/2007/09/12/apache-mod-rewrite for more info

Comment: That was it. 'Preciate it. I wasn't aware that mod_alias is triggered after mod_rewrite.

Comment: It's not terribly well known.  It is in the Apache docs, but I can never find the page w/ the module orders.  I ran into a similar problem several years ago and stopped using mod_alias as a result.